# Powershell Search-UnifiedAuditLog and export AuditData Field

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a function to export audit logs from Office 365.  When dumping the logs, the AuditData field contains what I feel is the useful information.  I'm looking to export only that field and convert it to a CSV.  Below is my function.

```
Function ExportAuditLog($User) {
    $logResults = @()
    if ($user -eq $null) {
        $user = SelectUser "Please select a user to audit"
    }

    $logData = Search-UnifiedAuditLog -StartDate ((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -EndDate (Get-Date) -UserIds $user -Operations MailboxLogin -Formatted | select AuditData
    foreach ($entry in $logData) {
        $logResults += $entry.AuditData
    }
    return $logResults
}
```

This is the output.

```
{
"CreationTime": "2018-12-01T14:08:55",
"Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Operation": "MailboxLogin",
"OrganizationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"RecordType": "ExchangeItem",
"ResultStatus": "Succeeded",
"UserKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"UserType": "Regular",
"Version": 1,
"Workload": "Exchange",
"UserId": "user@domain.com",
"ClientIPAddress": "1.2.3.4",
"ClientInfoString": 
"Client=Microsoft.Exchange.Autodiscover; Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Outlook 16.0.11001; Pro)",
"ExternalAccess": false,
"InternalLogonType": 0,
"LogonType": 0,
"LogonUserSid": "x-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx",
"MailboxGuid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"MailboxOwnerSid": "x-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx",
"MailboxOwnerUPN": "user@domain.com",
"OrganizationName": "domain.com",
"OriginatingServer": "",
"SessionId": ""
}
```

My goal is to have the first part of each line serve as the column header and the second part is the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet to convert the field into a Powershell object:

```
$logResults += ConvertFrom-Json $entry.AuditData
```

Then use the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to export it to a csv file:

```
$logResults | Export-Csv -Path AuditData.csv -NoTypeInformation
```